# Spring dataflow and GCP Pub Sub

Tags: microservices, google-cloud-pubsub, spring-cloud-dataflow, event-driven-design

I'm building an event-driven microservice architecture, which is supposed to be Cloud agnostic (as much as possible).
 Since this is initially going in GCP and I don't want to spend a long time in configurations and all that, I was going to use GCP's Pub/Sub directly for the event queue and would take care of other Cloud implementations later, but then I came across Spring Cloud Dataflow, which seemed nice because these are Spring Boot microservices and I needed a way to orchestrate them.

- Does Spring Cloud Dataflow support Pub Sub as it's event queue?
- Would it make my life easier in terms of configuration and setup going that path, rather than choosing a non native broker?

Answer (score 2):

It'd be useful first to unpack the Spring Cloud Stream's "binder abstraction" because it is using this framework, you'd have a portable event-driven streaming application, which can run locally in your laptop or any cloud of your choice against the desired message broker.

Learn more about the binder-abstraction [here](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.1.0.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-overview-binder-abstraction). Here are all the available [binder implementations](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/#binder-implementations) of choice. Google PubSub is an option, and it is maintained by Google [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/master/spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder).

Now, let's talk about Spring Cloud Data Flow (SCDF). Once when you have built the streaming applications, you could use SCDF to design+create a data pipeline made of such applications. There's the option to mix and reuse the [collection of utility applications](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.0.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/#applications) that we build, maintain, and release as well. The utility applications can be packaged with Google PubSub or other binders. More details [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/docs/Darwin.SR3/reference/htmlsingle/#customizing-binder).

When you deploy the data pipeline, SCDF will resolve and download the individual applications to deploy them *natively* on platforms like Kubernetes or Cloud Foundry. We have users doing the same in a variety of cloud infrastructure (VMs, Bare-metal, EC2, Rackspace, etc.), including DIY platforms, too.

While also automating the deployment of the applications, SCDF will automate the configuration setup based on naming conventions derived from stream/task and application names as a combination. So, when the apps bootstrap, they would have automatically received the connection configurations (from SCDF) and as well the destination/topic to connect to along with the other metadata to reason through a collection of apps as a "stream" or a "task/batch" data pipeline. This allows you to monitor and manage the pipelines centrally.

Lastly, there's the native ability in SCDF to rolling-upgrade/rolling-downgrade 1 or many applications in a data pipeline without impacting the upstream or downstream consumers in production. More details [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.0.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-local-spring-cloud-dataflow-streams-upgrading). There's a [webinar recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n6fS-KmN0zI&feature=youtu.be) (demo starts at ~41.25) on how to do with CI/CD automation.

Comment: To use SCDF on GCP, you'd have to either use the K8s or Cloud Foundry-specific SCDF implementations. More details can be found on the [reference guide](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/#platform-implementations). Once when you do, to globally supply Google PubSub connection credentials, so all the apps can receive it when they start, you can do that via ["Common Application Properties"](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.7.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-global-properties).