# Spring cloud data flow over Google Pub/Sub

Tags: spring, google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have worked with spring cloud data flow and rabbitmq and kafka but i would like to know if it would be possible to install scdf with google pub/sub.

I don't want to create a stream (new app spring cloud stream) with source or sink to gcp i want google pub/sub over spring cloud data flow server to use as an intermediate messaging broker.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use Spring dataflow and GCP Pub Sub [link](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/concepts/streams/).

> Through the use of one of many Spring Cloud Stream Binders, many
>    different messaging middleware products can be used. The following
>    popular platforms are among the list supported by Spring Cloud Data
>    Flow:
>
> 1.Kafka Streams
>
> 2.Amazon Kinesis
>
> 3.Google Pub/Sub
>
> 4.Solace PubSub+
>
> 5.Azure Event
>
> > Hubs You can find more information like the the current list of Spring
> >     Cloud Stream Binders here library as a dependency to the application.

Spring Cloud Stream supports Google PubSub (partner maintained) binder implementation [link](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/master/spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder).

Here you can find a related SO question [Spring dataflow and GCP Pub Sub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54600712/spring-dataflow-and-gcp-pub-sub).